# Is the 'inflated abdomen' of a pregnant woman referred as an abdomen or it has a specific name?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Is the casual 'inflated abdomen' of a pregnant woman still referred as an **abdomen** or it has a **specific name**? (formally rather than slang). I couldn't find information about that, but it seems that some times it referred as a **uterus** or womb. Isn't it?

> I  think that it's not appropriate for a stranger to touch [a ---?]
>   of a pregnant woman, even-though in some of the culture it's considered normal.

N.b. Now I found [here](https://www.scarymommy.com/10-reasons-you-shouldnt-touch-pregnant-woman-belly/) that it's referred as '**belly**'. That's a slang or formal English?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In decreasing order of formality, common and appropriate ways of discussing this body part are **abdomen**, **stomach** and **belly**. Belly is certainly not the most formal term, but I wouldn't call it slang.

Referring to a woman's "pregnant belly" is very common--much more common than "pregnant stomach" or "pregnant abdomen." (See this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pregnant%20belly%2C%20pregnant%20stomach%2C%20pregnant%20abdomen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpregnant%20belly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpregnant%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpregnant%20abdomen%3B%2Cc0))

"Inflated abdomen" is not a common or idiomatic term.

Womb and uterus both refer to the internal structure where the baby grows, not anything that can be touched from the outside.